# Why are migrants crossing the English Channel from the EU to the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

I'm a UK expat living in France and I've been reading the UK news, which is covering a decent number of migrants and refugees crossing the English Channel in the hopes of reaching the UK ([example](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-53717440)).

I understand these migrants are fleeing terrible warzones, but they seem to be crossing with these dinghies from Calais and various places in France. As someone who is British, I am confused as to why they wish to seek refuge in a country which recently voted to leave the European Union, especially given that immigration was one of the key reasons that many voted to Leave. The UK itself also has a long history of, and a current issue with, explicit racism and Islamophobia.

Is there any evidence that their lives would be better in the UK than in France, despite the UK's racist and narrow-minded attitude towards migrants, such as better state support or improved likelihood of receiving asylum?